# Does Google Cloud Endpoint Cache data locally

Tags: android, google-app-engine, caching

I am using Google Cloud Endpoint with an android app. Do I have to explicitly cache data that I mean to reuse? Or does the endpoint store data for me so that the same call twice in a row pull from a local cache? If it's not done automatically, is there a setting I can use?

If the question is still not clear, here is what I mean. Say I query my server for `common dogs in america` and then display the list in my DogActivity. If I then move away from that activity with `finish()` or by destroying it, if you will: The next time I return to my DogActivity and query my endpoint, does it call the server anew or is the data pulled from local cache by the endpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A built int Cache is not implemented on endpoint generated libs (would be a cool [feature to request](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list) though). So any info you retrieve will be lost unless you explicitly store it yourself.

Comment: did you request it yet?

Comment: no, I thought You'd like the honors. Send me the link tough I'll start it ASAP

Comment: someone beat me to it. Probably someone who read this question. But we can give it a star. The more stars the more quickly they will add the feature. https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11875

Comment: starred, seems like someone picked up on your question :)